# Вывод графиков по данным множества колонок датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

В датафрейме 17 колонок. Кладу их заголовки в список и перебираю циклом. Есть ли более изящный или производительный способ выводить много графиков?

```
features = list(data.columns)
i = 1
f_size = (25, 20)
plt.figure(figsize=f_size)
for feature in features:
    plt.subplot(5, 4, i)
    data[feature].hist(edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)
    plt.title(feature)
    i += 1
```

[image: вот эти графики]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пожалуй, нет.
Но вот счетчик можно реализовать симпатичнее:

```
features = list(data.columns)
f_size = (25, 20)
plt.figure(figsize=f_size)
for i, feature in enumerate(features):
    plt.subplot(5, 4, i+1)
    data[feature].hist(edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)
    plt.title(feature)
```